# Is there $f(x), g(x)$ with ratio limit of $\infty$ or $c$ so that *neither* $f=O(g(x))$ nor $g=O(f(x))$?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

Is there $f(x), g(x)$ with ratio limit of $\infty$ or $c$ so that *neither* $f=O(g(x))$ nor $g=O(f(x))$?

At first I thought about $f(x)=2x$ and $g(x)=x^{(1+\cos x)}$ but I got confused with the proof.

Comment: Say you are considering the limit as $x \to +\infty$. Then if neither of these holds, we know that $f/g, g/f$ are both not bounded. But if $f/g \to c \neq 0[x \to +\infty]$ then these $f/g, g/f$ are bounded simultaneously. So, no, no $f,g$ can satisfy your requirement.

Comment: @xbh thank you for comment, can you elaborate more on the end of your proof? ("But if f/g→c≠0[x→+∞] then these f/g,g/f are bounded simultaneously")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you are considering the limit as $x \to +\infty$. Then if neither of these holds, we know that $f/g, g/f$ are both not bounded. But if $f/g \to c \neq 0[x \to +\infty]$ then these $f/g, g/f$ are bounded simultaneously. So, no, no $f,g$ can satisfy your requirement.

**Update**

If $f/g \to c \neq 0$, then since $-2\newcommand\abs[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right \rvert} \abs c \leqslant c \leqslant 2 \abs c$, we get that for sufficiently large $x$, $\abs {f/g} \leqslant 2 \abs c$ which is exactly what $f = O(g)$ means. For $g/f \to 1/c \neq 0$, we can argue similarly.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
    k^{2k}, &x\in(2,2+1)& \\
    k^{2k+1}, &x\in(2+1,2+2)&
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
    k^{2k-2}, &x\in(2,2+1)& \\
    k^{2k+2}, &x\in(2+1,2+2)&
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Then $\varliminf f/g = 0, \varlimsup f/g = +\infty$, and the limit $\lim f/g$ does not exist. Did I read the OP wrong?

Comment: @xbh. I know, thanks. It is example/hint, which can be elaborated. I brought case when neither one is big-$O$ of another is fulfilled.